# How do I change the disk size with mkdosfs

Tags: command-line, partitioning, sd-card, execute-command, fat32

So I recently have received a 256GB SD Card on eBay for pretty cheap, but turns out that the factory part number printed on the back plastic was listed as an 8GB card.

It was modified from the seller to appear to hold 256GB and not its actual size.

I found out that there is a software in Linux called 'mkdosfs' (that also has a [Windows](http://www1.mager.org/mkdosfs/) compiled version, which is the one I am using, but essentially the same).

I applied the default script to the SD Card but that actually reduced the size read to 4GB.

[image: The shown disk size from Windows]

I further investigated to find that actually while running there is an error, that appears for half a second before closing, I managed to grab a screenshot of this error:
[image: The half-second error that appears while attempting to run mkdosfs]

This is the script I am using to run mkdosfs on Windows (where H: is the drive letter of the SD card)

```
mkdosfs -n "8GB" -v H: 8386900
```

Can anyone tell me how to change the script to output an 8GB disk as the result (I am pretty sure it is something to do with the last number)

Thanks, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even though you're saying you have Linux installed (which may or may not be a supported version of Ubuntu), you're running Windows in the instance of your issue.  It's a Windows application and Windows environment.  This is off topic for Askubuntu.  Try using a Windows support forum such as http://superuser.com.  If you're running an unsupported version of Ubuntu (an EOL version) there's a change the error you experience might already be resolved in the current version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you bought a drive advertised to be able to hold 256 GB but that can only hold up 8 GB, you should return it and get a refund from the seller because they didn't sell the promised product. If the seller and/or manufacturer were willing to defraud you based on the size of the drive, who knows what other defects or dormant faults the drive has. I wouldn't trust it with anything even in the first 8 GB.

---

For a *technical solution*, instead of fumbling around with file system tools you should instead *repartition* the drive so that it's partition(s) only cover(s) the first 8 GB (or whatever size is working), then format the resulting partition(s) with whatever file system(s) you like. The respective file system tools will create file systems that span the entire target partition by default.

You can use your favourite partition manager (e. g. Gnome Disks, KDE Partition Manager, GParted) to repartition the drive. I'll give you two command-line based examples below because they're easy to reproduce. Let's assume that the drive in question has the kernel name `/dev/sdz`.

#### Using `fdisk`

1. Start `fdisk` and point it to the drive:

   ```sh
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdz
   ```
2. Replace the partition table with a new one (menu option `o`).
3. Create a new partition (`n`),

   1. make it a primary partition (`p`),
   2. make it the first partition (`1`),
   3. choose the first sector at the suggested offset of 1 MiB (`2048` or no entry),
   4. choose the desired size of 8 GiB (= 8192 MiB) minus the 1 MiB from above (`+8191M`),
4. (optionally) print the resulting partition table to verify you did as intended (`p`),
5. (optionally) set the partition type to "W95 FAT32 (LBA)"<sup>1</sup> (`t`, then `c`)
6. write the new partition table to the device (`w`),
7. ask the Linux kernel to reread the partition table:

   ```sh
   sudo partprobe /dev/sdz
   ```

#### Using `sfdisk`

If you don't want to go through a bunch of menus you can also use `sfdisk` to specify a partition table (set `size_gb` to the desired size in GiB):

```sh
size_gb=8

sudo sfdisk /dev/sdz <<EOF
unit: sectors
: start=2048, size=$((($size_gb << 21) - (1 << 11))), Id=c
EOF
```

Like with `fdisk` you need to ask the kernel to reread the partition table:

```sh
sudo partprobe /dev/sdz
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The default partition type for new partitions created with `fdisk` is "Linux" but both types should be fine. All major operating systems (Linux, Windows and OS X) will recognise the partition content correctly with either partition type. There are some corner cases with third-party tools that choose to expect a particular partition type for whatever reason.

Comment: Creating an appropriately-sized partition is likely to be the simplest *technical* solution; however, I'd like to emphasize the last paragraph of this answer -- if the description in the question is accurate, NaturalistUbuntu is the victim of fraud, and eBay is likely to back up a claim against the seller. Even if you think the price was fair for a card 1/32 the advertised size, I'd be wary about trusting a card that's been monkeyed with in this way, so I'd recommend getting a refund.

Comment: I would love to, but I got this card 1 years ago, well after eBay can or would refund or step in, I was already to 7.5 gigs used and started adding data, then I realized that some of my stuff was either corrupted or completely gone. That also being said, the original seller deleted both his eBay and Paypal accounts, so no refund for me. (Dammit these Chinese eBay scammers are good).

Comment: @NaturalistUbuntu: I don't know about your local consumer protection laws but in the EU the seller is still liable for all defects that existed at the moment of sale even if you only discover them years later (and it's no defect that would be apparent during a "first inspection" by a layman). The general sales warranty for technical products is 2 years. Also, this is likely fraud in which case there are no statutes of limitation on these things because the defect is deliberate.

Comment: @RodSmith: Excellent point! I added a sentence to the non-technical part of my answer and moved it to the top.

Comment: Thanks, David, but this guy is across the planet, what is point going to international court over 8gig-256gig conflict.

Comment: No reason to go to court. I doubt  you bought the device *directly* from the seller but through some sales platform like Amazon or Ebay both of which offer relatively uncomplicated fraud protection as do many payment providers like Visa, Matercard, or Paypal.